# Upload missing required dSYMs through uploader tool

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

How to upload dSYM file. please help us. I am using  “Pods/Fabric” folder of your Xcode project directory

[image]

finally i got issue

```
vicky-MacBook-Air-2:~ vicky$ /Users/vicky/Documents/Office/CAADE\ MAIN/Caade_12.2/Caade\ 12.2/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -a <85ffrf2c3dc15de343dfdf0bbbbdfe083115fb50> -p ios /Users/vicky/Desktop/CTCaade.app.dSYM 

-bash: 89ffbf2c3dc15dee4677690bbbbdfe083115fb50: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried just using the generic path specified in the doc, instead of manually pointing toward your dSYM?

Comment: hi bro, can u explain ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#initialize-crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize Crashlytics by adding a run script to your project’s build phase. The run script allows Xcode to automatically upload your project’s dSYM file whenever your app crashes so that Crashlytics can automatically generate crash reports. 
- Make sure your new build phase is the project's last build phase or Crashlytics can't initialize properly.
- make sure Fabric org id is correct.

If you still get in to the issues - Write to the FirebaseSupport and include your app name bundle id , Firebase Project id.

Comment: Hi app in live, but showing missing dSYM file. what can i do. I sent mail to firebase team.

Comment: If support is able to resolve, please be sure to update your post with the answer.